# Responsive Grid Implementation in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: layout, xamarin, xamarin.forms, grid-layout

What would be the right way to create a responsive fluid grid in Xamarin.Forms? In the CSS world, this can be accomplished by using inline-block divs or flexboxes. What is the equivalent in Xamarin.Forms? (I don't consider checking screen sizes programatically and changing the column number as a responsive solution but rather an adaptive one as in media queries.)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no equivalent in Xamarin.Forms.
You have to query the device type and/or the screen-resolution maybe also the device orientation an then implement different layouts for phones and tablets and/or device orientation, if you want to optimize your app.